# Function looping through object keys throws undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, object, ecmascript-6, foreach

I'm trying to iterate through an Inventory object when the sale fucntion is called, and it should check the article requested and its amount.

Always updating the inventory when a sale is made, and if an article inside de object reaches 0 the article should be deleted from the inventory.

So far I tried this with a forEach and a simple For but with no luck.

I always get an 'Undefined' when calling the function.

```
const inventory = {
    shoes: 10,
    socks: 6,
    shirts: 10,
    pants: 5,
}

function sale(arti, amount){
    Object.keys(inventory).forEach(key => {
        let keyitem = inventory[key]

        if(keyitem === arti){
            if(keyitem.val > amount){
                keyitem.val - amount
                return 'Article sold'
            } else if (keyitem.val === 0){
                keyitem.val - amount
                delete inventory.key
                return 'Article sold'
            } else if (keyitem.val < amount){
                return 'Theres no inventory for the amount you requested'
            }
        }
    });
}

sale('shoes', 7)
```

Function should return if the sale can be made and update the Inventory object.

So if I call sale('shoes', 7) and then console log the object, shoes should now read 3.

Comment: there is no `return` value from `forEach`. If you want to return then use `for (const key of Object.keys(inventory)) { ... }` or `for (const [key, keyItem] of Object.entries(inventory)) { ... }`.  Also `delete inventroy.key` makes no sense. I think you wanted `delete inventory[key]`

Comment: The way your code is written, `keyitem` will **never** equal the `arti` parameter. Return values from the `.forEach()` callback are ignored in any case.

Comment: Oh that's right, I tried changing the returns to console.logs but I got the same 'Undefined' as before

Comment: `delete inventory.key` is also faulty code - it attempts to delete the literal key `"key"` from `inventory`. Use square brackets to delete the key with the value contained by your "key" variable: `delete inventory[key]`

Comment: delete inventory.key shouldn't work as you don't have any key you're selling on the inventory object.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I'll make some updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't returns from a function within a `forEach` callback. You can use an actual `foreach` loop to acheive that though:

Here I have removed part of your code to show you how to returns from inside the `foreach` loop. there is still a few logics errors in your code but those are not the topics of this demonstration.

```js
const inventory = {
    shoes: 10,
    socks: 6,
    shirts: 10,
    pants: 5,
}

function sale(arti, amount){
    for(let key in inventory) {
      let keyitem = inventory[key]
        if(keyitem === 10){
          return "returns from inside the foreach loop";
        }
    }
   
}

console.log(sale('socks', 7));
```

Comment: I almost made it work!, the only thing I'm missing is to update the object. Thank you Nicolas!